# View with round corners not smooth

Tags: android, rounded-corners, android-shapedrawable

Have a look at my code below.

```
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#5a2705"));
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(2);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));
```

I am applying this as background to my `LinearLayout`, but the edges are not smooth. How can I fix this?

Here is the screenshot of how it looks.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using a `RoundRectShape` instead of the `CornerPathEffect`?

Comment: No i havent tried it, can you show me how?

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8186419

Comment: yes, i tried that but still the edges are not smooth, its still ugly as shown in the pic in my question, can you please let me know is there any other way

Answer (score 10):

Using a programmatically-created shape drawable as a View background results in the outer half of your stroke width getting cropped off (for reasons I don't know). Look closely at your image and you'll see that your stroke is only 1 pixel wide, even though you requested 2. That is why the corners look ugly. This effect will be much more apparent if you try a bigger stroke and radius such as 10 and 40, respectively.

Either use an XML drawable, which doesn't seem to have this problem, like in Harshit Jain's answer, or do the following if you must (or prefer to) use a programmatic solution.

**Solution:** Use a layer list to inset the rectangle by the amount that is being clipped (half the stroke width), like this:

```
float strokeWidth = 2;

ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#5a2705"));
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));

Drawable[] layers = {shapeDrawable};
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

int halfStrokeWidth = (int)(strokeWidth/2);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, halfStrokeWidth, halfStrokeWidth, halfStrokeWidth, halfStrokeWidth);
```

Then use the `layerDrawable` as your background. Here is a screen shot of the result of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I misinterpreted the problem to be that the outer and inner edges of the corner had the same radius, but it was in fact clipping. I was using drawRoundRect with RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()). The solution was much the same: to inset the RectF by half strokeWidth.

Comment: Thank you @FletcherJohns, was having the same problems but this fixed it

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating a separate xml file with a layout of the rounded rectangle. Such as:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="color_here"/>
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="color_here"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can tune this to your liking and use this XML file as a background in your main XML.

You can also try using **9Patch** which should already come with your SDK

Answer (score 1):

To cater such background requirement I prefer using 9-patch drawable.
Below are the pointer to get going with creating and using 9-patch drawable resources:

1. Developer Doc: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
2. Another explanation: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/
3. [Online tool](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top%5B%5D=25&top%5B%5D=50&right%5B%5D=25&right%5B%5D=50&bottom%5B%5D=25&bottom%5B%5D=50&left%5B%5D=25&left%5B%5D=50) to create 9-patch images. (Note: Modify the file extension to `*.9.png` while saving the image)

Comment: The Online tool you suggested is GREAT!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider `checking` [this](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/02/roundedimageview/) out.

`Rounded Image Views` by Vince

Comment: This helps a lot from my experience. And great page for UI.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue in a very simple way,

I was looking for a code which can be done programmatically and not via xml,

Here is the code:

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setCornerRadius(10);
    shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    shape.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#996633"));
```

You can set this like this : `view.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);`

The answer posted by **@Tenfour04** might also solve the issue but i havent tried as such.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using selector like this . This solution is the best you just need to set this selector to the background of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
         <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:startColor="@color/white"
          android:centerColor="@color/grey"
          android:endColor="@color/white"
          android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Choose color of your own.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem recently and came up with a different solution. IMHO the best solution is to create your own `Shape` implementation and use it to create a `ShapeDrawable`.

Below is a simple implementation of rounded rectangle, that will allow you to inset it's border.

```
class InsetRoundRectShape(
    private var radiusArray: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f),
    private var inset: RectF = RectF()
): RectShape() {

    private var innerRect: RectF = RectF()
    private var path: Path = Path()

    constructor(radius: Float, inset: RectF): this(floatArrayOf(radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius), inset)
    constructor(radius: Float, inset: Float): this(radius, RectF(inset, inset, inset, inset))

    init {
        if (radiusArray.size < 8) {
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("radius array must have >= 8 values")
        }
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }

    override fun getOutline(outline: Outline) {
        super.getOutline(outline)

        val radius = radiusArray[0]
        if(radiusArray.any { it != radius }) {
            outline.setConvexPath(path)
            return
        }

        val r = rect()
        outline.setRoundRect(ceil(r.left).toInt(), ceil(r.top).toInt(), floor(r.right).toInt(), floor(r.bottom).toInt(), radius)
    }

    override fun onResize(w: Float, h: Float) {
        super.onResize(w, h)
        val r = rect()
        path.reset()
        innerRect.set(r.left + inset.left, r.top + inset.top, r.right - inset.right, r.bottom - inset.bottom)
        if(innerRect.width() <= w && innerRect.height() <= h) {
            path.addRoundRect(innerRect, radiusArray, Path.Direction.CCW)
        }
    }

    override fun clone(): InsetRoundRectShape {
        val shape = super.clone() as InsetRoundRectShape
        shape.radiusArray = radiusArray.clone()
        shape.inset = RectF(inset)
        shape.path = Path(path)
        return shape
    }
}
```

Create ShapeDrawable like this

```
//Inset has to be half of strokeWidth
ShapeDrawable(InsetRoundRectShape(10f, 4f)).apply {
    this.paint.color = Color.BLUE
    this.paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    this.paint.strokeWidth = 8.dp
    this.invalidateSelf()
}
```